# How to implement a "Save as New" feature

Tags: xpages

I am looking to implement a "Save as new" button. This would essentially take an existing document and create a new copy of the document with all of the existing fields. This would need to be implemented from a document and not a viewPanel.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Are you reading from a file? which coding language are you coding in? To provide a general answer (with some assumption), you can read it into a stream and then use the save method to save it with a string path.

Comment: oh nevermind. sorry - i just saw an xpages tag. Not sure why this show up on my unanswered list. i'm not an expert in this area. Sorry.

Comment: @NKD: the language is XPages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Pass your NotesDocument or NotesXspDocument (sourceDoc) in your function call or otherwise define it based on your particular need.
2. Create a new NotesDocument (newDoc) in the target notesDatabase.
3. Use sourceDoc.copyAllItems() into the newDoc.
4. Save and - if desired - redirect to the newDoc.

I have a "services" feature in my CMS that allows the author to create a duplicate of the "service" with the following SSJS:

```
var service = {
...
  duplicate : function(thisDoc:NotesXspDocument) {
    try {
        var newDoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
        thisDoc.getDocument().copyAllItems(newDoc, true);
        var newId = newDoc.getItemValueString("id") + "-" + session.evaluate("@Unique").elementAt(0) + "-DUPLICATE";
        newDoc.replaceItemValue("id", newId);
        newDoc.save(true);

        context.redirectToPage("/service.xsp?id=" + newId + "&");

    } catch(e) {
        print(database.getTitle() + " SSJS Error for service.duplicate()");
        print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I read the IDs in my dataSources, which is why I'm passing through the newId value. If you're using the out-of-the-box dataSource setup, you'll want to change that to getUniversalID() and set the URL Parameters to "?action=openDocument&documentId=".

[edit]- Here is the script that will work for a standard data source

```
var newDoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
    currentDocument.getDocument().copyAllItems(newDoc, true);

    newDoc.save(true);
    var newId = newDoc.getUniversalID();
    context.redirectToPage("/entry.xsp/%24%24OpenDominoDocument.xsp?     documentId="+@Text(newId)+"&action=editDocument");
```

[edit] (Chris Toohey): I changed "document1" to "currentDocument" to better support the relative local/current NotesDocument dataSource (as someone could change the default dataSource name from "document1" and the suggested edited code wouldn't work).

Comment: Thanks Chris, that is what I needed to get it working. I added an edited version of your script that I got working.

Answer (score 2):

`NotesDatabase.createDocument()` and `NotesDocument.copyAllItems(destDoc)` should provide the functionality (or the corresponding Java equivalents). It's better performing than `NotesDocument.copyToDatabase()`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/DateAllFlatWeb/ad18d9bdca1141b1852576e8004ca5a1?OpenDocument

Comment: I should have specified, from the document and not from a view panel.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work under XPages, but if the document contains a '$VerOpt' notesItem (field name) with a valid setting in it (eg: "2") the database may create a new copy for you. You will have to arrange to set/clear the value as needed. If you wish to create the 'new version' on every save, the form has a default properties has a setting you can set. Search for this reserved fieldname for details.